# Pelting of Satan

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Can someone find for me the supposed Hadith which state that the reason for the pelting of the Jamaraat is to commemorate Ibrahim AS pelting Satan while on his way to sacrifice Isma'il AS? Is the Hadith authentic?

Answer (score 1):

A hadith on Abraham (عليه السلام) stoning the devil at the Jamaraat is recorded through Ibn Abbas in both Marfoo' and Mawqoof forms. The marfoo' versions are:

> عن ابن عباس: أن رسول الله-صلي الله عليه وسلم- قال: إن جبريل ذهب بإبراهيم إلى جمرة العقبة، فعرض له الشيطان، فرماه بسبع حصيات، فساخ، ثم أتى الجمرة الوسطى، فعرض له الشيطان، فرماه بسبع حصيات، فساخ، ثم أتى الجمرة القصوى، فعرض له الشيطان، فرماه بسبع حصيات، فساخ
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/1362#p2)</sup>

There is weakness in this particular chain due to the transmitter عطاء بن السائب as cited by for example [al-Haythami](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/919), [al-Arnaa’oot](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/2022#p1) and [al-Albani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12762/678#p1). His memory was effected in the latter part of his life and he began to make mitakes, so the correctness of the narrations from the latter period are doubtful and it is not clear in which period this hadith was heard from him. However it has been classed as Sahih by [Ibn Khuzaima](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1446/4941#p1), [Muhammad Shakir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/1362) and [al-Albani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32968/669).

It is also supported through a second chain from different transmitters:

> عن ابن عباس، رفعه قال: لما أتى إبراهيم خليل الله المناسك عرض له الشيطان عند جمرة العقبة فرماه بسبع حصيات حتى ساخ في الأرض، ثم عرض له عند الجمرة الثانية فرماه بسبع حصيات حتى ساخ في الأرض، ثم عرض له عند الجمرة الثالثة فرماه بسبع حصيات حتى ساخ في الأرض
>
> <sup>— [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/1745#p1) and [Sunan al-Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33024/11229#p1)</sup>

It has also been narrated as a mawqoof version in a third chain:

> قال ابن عباس: إن إبراهيم لما أمر بالمناسك عرض له الشيطان عند المسعى فسابقه، فسبقه إبراهيم، ثم ذهب به جبريل إلى جمرة العقبة، فعرض له الشيطان، فرماه بسبع حصيات حتى ذهب، ثم عرض له عند الجمرة الوسطى، فرماه بسبع حصيات حتى ذهب
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/36519) and [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/2658)</sup>

Comment: The Hadith mentions Isaac AS as the child to be sacrificed and it is supposedly linked back to the Prophet SAW. The Hadith can't be true.

Comment: @Afiq There has been difference of opinion on whether it was Isaac or Ishmael, so the hadith can't be false just because of that. Even so there are versions of the hadith where Isaac is not mentioned or where Ishmael is mentioned.

Comment: My only concern is the idea that these stones *represent* Satan. I can't help but thinking that this is aniconic